# How to get hold of the xml message in JaxRs

Tags: xml, jax-rs

I have my hook as

```
@POST
@Path("add")
@Produces("text/html")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public String addCustomer(SiebelMessage siebMsg) {
  // TODO: Log the XML message here
  return siebMsg.getAccount().get(0).getHomePage(); // works
  }
}
```

I want to log the actual XML message in the local file system, how do I get the access.

Comment: did u manage to find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jersey, you could use [LoggingFilter](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/LoggingFilter.java?rev=5478) jersey provides (or get inspired by that to implement your filter that does something similar), if you don't want to depend on implementation specific API, you'll have to use JAXB to write out the XML for the SiebelMessage.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to access the XML that I send in the HTTP body as a POST, in the same method: addCustomer(). for example I was able to modify the method to auto inject the Context info, as shown below.`code' public String addCustomer(SiebelMessage siebMsg,@Context UriInfo ui ) {
   System.out.println(servletContext);
   MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = ui.getQueryParameters();
   MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParams = ui.getPathParameters();
   return siebMsg.getListOfSitAccountUpdateBmc().getAccount().get(0).getHomePage();
  } 'code'

Answer (score 0):

In CXF you need to get hold of the MesageContext

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/ext/MessageContext.java

That has a getHttpServletRequest() method. The CXF prorietrary way is to

```
((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext()
```

But you can use the @Context annotation

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Contextannotations

Answer (score 0):

The multipart/form-data is the trick as in the following

```
    @POST
@Path("addCustomer")
@Produces("multipart/form-data")
@Consumes({"multipart/form-data"}) 
public String addCustomer(String formData) {
  System.out.println("The formData\n" + formData);
  return "SEEYA";
}
```

The next part is how to UnMarshall the XML to Pojo. which is a different topic.